# Pydroid 3 Code Analysis: what triggers fatal?

Tags: android, python-3.x, pylint

I have bought the premium version of Pydroid3 and was wondering what triggers "[F]atal - Fatal Error. Processing has terminated", I have found an example for all other code analysis, but not for this one

```
"""Refactor: R1722 Consider using sys.exit()"""
exit()
```

```
"""Convention: C0304 Final newline missing"""
```

```
"""Warning: W0104 Statement seems to have no effect"""
1 + 1
```

```
"""Error E0001 invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 2)"""
+
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rename your script and go back to the editor you can get a fatal error message:

```
"""Fatal: F0001 No module named /storage/emulated/0/Download/PVZ2tools-alpha/PVZ2tools-alpha/OBBEdit/patch (1).py"""
```

Problem solved!
[image]